# python-flask db.session.commit() is not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The problem is when user tries 'forgot password' option. It creates new `reset_key` for verification, but the new key is not getting updated into DB.

```
@app.route('/login/forgot/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forgot():
   form = ResetLoginForm(request.form)
   #There's no session yet. User just pointing to /login/forgot url.

   if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
      user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

   if not user:
     flash('The username or email incorrect')
     return render_template('forgot.html', form=form)

   reset_key = generate_key() ## this creates a new key, but how update  this key into db?
   #tried something like 
   user.reset_key = reset_key 
   db.session.add(user)
   db.session.commit()
   #this is not working. Is it due to session is not started or something?
```

Thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: Remove the line that adds a new user record: `db.session.add(user)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()` will return a `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` object. As its doc says:

> Query is the source of all SELECT statements generated by the ORM,
>   both those formulated by end-user query operations as well as by high
>   level internal operations such as related collection loading. It
>   features a generative interface whereby successive calls return a new
>   Query object, a copy of the former with additional criteria and
>   options associated with it.

So you just get a copied object, so your change will not work;

You can use like this:
`user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(email==form.email.data).first()`
and then you can change `user` attrs

Comment: I think `filter_by` has one more equals symbol than it should, right, i.e.  `...(email=form.email.data)...`?

Answer (score 0):

`user = db.session.query(User).first()` solved problem.